# error en consulta MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy Realizando una consulta la cual me devuelve valores vacíos cuando dicha columna tiene datos con esos valores esta es la consulta.

```
select * from 'clase' 
where 'fk_id_familia' = 3 
and 'fk_id_familia' = 6 
and 'fk_id_familia' = 2
```

Y estos son los datos que tiene la tabla:

```
$clase = array(
      array('id_clase' => '25','clase' => 'Equipo Veterinario','fk_id_familia' => '1'),
      array('id_clase' => '26','clase' => 'Vestuario Para Pacientes','fk_id_familia' => '2'),
      array('id_clase' => '27','clase' => 'Agendas y Accesorios','fk_id_familia' => '3'),
      array('id_clase' => '28','clase' => 'Suministros De Escritorio','fk_id_familia' => '4'),
      array('id_clase' => '29','clase' => 'Muebles Para La Clinica Dental','fk_id_familia' => '5'),
      array('id_clase' => '30','clase' => 'Formulas y Productos Para Apoyo Nutritivo','fk_id_familia' => '6'),
      array('id_clase' => '31','clase' => 'Espejos Quirurjicos','fk_id_familia' => '7')
    );
```

Y esta es la estructura de la tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE 'clase' (
      'id_clase' int(11) NOT NULL,
      'clase' varchar(500) NOT NULL,
      'fk_id_familia' int(11) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;`
```

Comment: Así se llama la columna de la tabla? `fk_id_familia`? podrías poner la estructura de la tabla por favor

Comment: es **id_clase**, **clase**, **fk_id_familia**

Comment: de hecho el array que esta publicado en la pregunta fue exportado directamente de php myadmin y pues si consulto un solo elemento ejemplo `select * from 'clase' where 'fk_id_familia' = 3`  Si funciona

Comment: @Yikarus ya agregue la estructura a la pregunta

Comment: Para futuras preguntas, visto que usaste `<br>  <br>` para saltos de línea, ten en cuenta que SO no es un editor HTML, es mejor que des `Enter Enter` cuando escribas tu pregunta. En cuanto a los bloques de código, los puedes pegar normal, seleccionar y luego identar todo el bloque con el símbolo **`{ }`** de la parte superior. De ese modo la pregunta será más legible, como podrás ver actualmente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error está en tu consulta, literalmente estás diciendo:

"Tráeme los elementos que tengan fk_id_familia = 1 Y fk_id_familia = 2 Y fk_id_familia = 3", es decir estás buscando un elemento que tenga los 3 valores en el mismo campo lo cual en tu caso no se da.

Debes cambiar tu consulta por esto:

```
select * from 'clase' where 'fk_id_familia' = 3 or 'fk_id_familia' = 6 or 'fk_id_familia' = 2
```

O bien podrías usar un IN

```
select * from 'clase' where 'fk_id_familia' in (3, 6, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

usa un IN asi:

```
select * from clase where fk_id_familia in (2,3,6);
```